# Unchanged association condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

An element can be associated with different models through the polymorphic association *elementable*. Because I want to use nested forms, I have to make associations for the different models explicit (association *element_recommendation*).

The following code works as intended:

```
class Element < ActiveRecord::Base    
  belongs_to :elementable, :polymorphic => true, :dependent => :destroy

  belongs_to :element_recommendation, ->(element) { 
  if element.elementable_type == 'ElementRecommendation' 
    where('true = true') 
  else 
    none
  end }, :class_name => "ElementRecommendation", :foreign_key => "elementable_id"
  [..]
```

But I'm unhappy with the lambda in the *element_recommendation* association. It's an all or nothing association. The *none*-part is cognizable, but the *take it as it is*-part is not obvious. How can I make *where('true = true')* recognizable?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution while I was writing the question:

```
belongs_to :element_recommendation, ->(element) { 
  if element.elementable_type == 'ElementRecommendation' 
    self
  else 
    none
  end }, :class_name => "ElementRecommendation", :foreign_key => "elementable_id"
```